# sending byte[] ( more than 20 KB) throught wcf to silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, image, arrays

i am sending byte[] (image) through wcf to silverlight, and from silverlight to wcf, everything works well as long as the byte[] (image) is less than 20KB, but when it's bigger, it doesn't work
when i try to save the image uploaded in silverlight and send it to wcf to save it in the DB

i receive: The remote server returned an error: NotFound"
and debugger doesn't reach the save method in the wcf service

Answer (score 2):

Check the binding configuration. It has properties for getting/setting max receive data bytes: check "maxReceivedMessageSize" property (representing the size in bytes).

Edit: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299.aspx) you can find details about all binding configuration properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serialzing objects over the wire, also make sure you maxItemsInObjectGraph is large enough. I ran into this problem thinking it was bytes, but actually turned out to be the # of items in my List<>.